# How do I display facebook wall posts of users who logs in to my website?

Tags: php, facebook

I have surfed a lot found many answers as well in stackoverflow.com but nothing suits my criteria.

```
$graph_url  = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?access_token=user_acces_token";


$user = json_decode(file_get_contents($graph_url));
```

This is what I am using so far, When I change 'me' keyword with the users id, it does not display anything, and if I keeps 'me' then it displays my wall posts only when an other user signs in!

Comment: Better to always use /me and use that users access token

Comment: yes I have tried that, but it does not do anything! I just see an blank page!

Comment: Kind of strange behaviour you describe here. I guess you're just using a single User Access Token, right? And if so, there is your problem.

Comment: @Tobi, This is how I am getting the access token.
$access_token = $Fb->getAccessToken();
I guess this not a static one!

Comment: If you're not including a useful amount of your code nobody will be able to help.